# Speed up query through laravel relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

There are 3 models:

```
First (first_id)
Connection (connection_id, first_id, product_id)
Second (second_id, product_id)
```

I would like to connect the three models together using laravel relationships

`First`->joined to Connection though `first_id`
  `Connection`->joined to First through `first_id`, & joined to `Second` through `product_id`
  `Second` -> joined to Connection through `product_id`

So: First joined to Second through Connection `first_id`, `product_id`

Is this possible to do using something like `HasManyThrough`?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your First model:

```
public function second () {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Second::class, 
        Connection::class, 
        'product_id', // Foreign key on connection table
        'product_id', // Foreign key on second table
        'first_id', // Local key on first table
        'first_id' // Local key on connection table
    );
}
```

Based on your description the column names should work.

In tinker you can validate if it's hooked up correctly by doing something like `First::first()->second`.

Comment: Working perfectly now, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what type of relationship Your first model and second model shares as well as what type of relation second and third model shares.

if consider your first model `First` and second model `Second` shares a one-to-one relation, as well as `Second` model and `Third` models shares one-to-one relationships.

It will be `$first->second->third;` //no has many through relationship requires

If your `First` model and `Second` models shares as hasMany-belongs to relation than you need to use hasManyThrough relationship

example from [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

```
class Country extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Post',
            'App\User',
            'country_id', // Foreign key on users table...
            'user_id', // Foreign key on posts table...
            'id', // Local key on countries table...
            'id' // Local key on users table...
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using nested relationships.

**Nested Eager Loading**
To eager load nested relationships, you may use "dot" syntax. For example, let's eager load all of the book's authors and all of the author's personal contacts in one Eloquent statement:

```
$books = App\Book::with('author.contacts')->get();
```

Book Model:

```
public function author() 
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Author');
}
```

Author Model:

```
public function contacts() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Author');
}
```

Documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships